# Phonegap buildi automazation

Tags: cordova, build-automation, phonegap-build

I was wondering if there is any way to automatize my phonegap build. Next to setting up my plugin I would more likely to copy app resources from an other directory into www folder of my phonegap build.

Let's pretend there is a structure like this:

```
--application
  |--com.phonegap.application
    |--platforms
    |--plugins
    |--merges
    |--www (destination folder)
  |--application
    |--www (source folder)
```

So the question is: **Is there any way to copy all files from source-folder to destination-folder when building phonegap through CLI ?**

Thanks a lot for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just write a short bash script?

Something like

```
cp -rf application/www/* com.phonegap.application/www
phonegap build ...
```

And place it in the root application directory.

Comment: I thouth there might be a more comfortable way, like specifiying it in phonegap, but good hint. Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know the phonegap cli does not include that feature.